# JavaFX Layout complie time

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to achieve this but I'm running into some problems. I got the rough skeleton, but for example when I try to add the output TextArea to my Vbox container, I get an error.

The error is: `The method addAll(int, Collection<? extends Node>) in the type List<Node> is not applicable for the arguments (HBox, HBox, HBox, Button, TextArea)`

EDIT: I had the wrong import for the TextArea, I had the awt instead of the javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

```
        GridPane g1 = new GridPane();
        HBox firstRow = new HBox();
        firstRow.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Label name = new Label("Name: ");
        TextField nameInput = new TextField();

        g1.add(name, 0, 0);
        g1.add(nameInput, 1, 0);
        firstRow.getChildren().addAll(g1);

        GridPane g2 = new GridPane();
        HBox secondRow = new HBox();
        secondRow.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Label city = new Label("City: ");
        TextField cityInput = new TextField();

        g2.add(city, 0, 0);
        g2.add(cityInput, 1, 0);
        secondRow.getChildren().addAll(g2);


        HBox thirdRow = new HBox();
        thirdRow.setSpacing(20);
        thirdRow.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        RadioButton radioName = new RadioButton("Name");
        RadioButton radioCity = new RadioButton("City");
        RadioButton radioZip = new RadioButton("Zip");
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        radioName.setToggleGroup(group);
        radioCity.setToggleGroup(group);
        radioZip.setToggleGroup(group);
        thirdRow.getChildren().addAll(radioName, radioCity, radioZip);

        Button search = new Button("Search");

        HBox fifthRow = new HBox();
        TextArea output = new TextArea();


        VBox container = new VBox();
        container.getChildren().addAll(firstRow, secondRow, thirdRow, search);
```

Comment: What error is that? As far as I can see, the code should not produce errors but might not produce the result which you want.

Comment: If I add this TextArea output = new TextArea(); to my container container.getChildren().addAll(firstRow, secondRow, thirdRow, search, output); I get                                                                                           
             Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method addAll(int, Collection<? extends Node>) in the type List<Node> is not applicable for the arguments (HBox, HBox, HBox, Button, TextArea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question wasn't too clear initially because you did not include the error you saw. The problem is because you have imported the wrong `TextArea`, which import statements are also not included in your question.

You need to change `import java.awt.TextArea;` into `import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;`. The former is a control for AWT, while the latter is the control for JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

As it says, you need to add a child "ouput" which is TextBox element to a container.

```
container.getChildren().addAll(firstRow, secondRow, thirdRow, search, output);
```

Aslo I would like to note that you need to arrange elements in proper order, as this code is not pragmatic at all.